# Is everyone today from two or three tribes?

Tags: shevatim-12-tribes, asereth-hashvatim-ten-tribes

I am a little hazy on the division of the ten tribes and the two tribes. Is everyone today from the two "nonlost tribes"? Are only Yisraelim? Is it possible Jews today are from the other tribes?

Comment: Any reason to think it is impossible?

Comment: No, but I am curious what the overwhelming opinion is.

Comment: Off the top of my head it seems that Jews (in the popular conception, not including Bnei Menashe or other groups) are from the Kingdom of Judah which was 3 tribes primarily, plus (from what I recall) a smattering of refugees from the other kingdom. So there is a chance that someone today could trace back, to a limited degree, to another tribe but most are from Judah, some are from Benjamin and some from Levi.

Comment: I once heard (but I can't remember the source) that when the kingdoms split, the jews who wanted to keep serving G-d moved into the Kingdom of Yehuda. If so there would be representatives of all 12 tribes that were not lost.

Answer (score 1):

[Medrash Talpiyos - page 162](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20804&st=&pgnum=162&hilite=) from the same author as the Sheivet Musar says that Askenazic Jewry is mainly from Binyamin.

I have heard that the Chida writes that Ashkenazi Jewry mainly comes from Binyamin, and that Sefardic Jewry mainly comes from Yehuda. (Need to find the written source)

Besides that there are Kohanim and Leviyim mixed in amongst both Ashkenazi and Sefardic Jewry.

I have also heard that there may be a minute amount of some of the other Shevatim mixed in.

Comment: so i guess moshiach tzidkeinu will be sefardi :P

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Please cite the relevant text in your answer

Comment: @YaakovPinchas Click on the link to see the relevant text

Comment: @GershonGold and where in the link is the relevant text?

Comment: @YaakovPinchas on top on the left

Answer (score 1):

There are two sources I can think of that clearly show that there are Jews from other tribes even after the Ten Tribes were exiled:

The first is from the [Talmud](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.4a.4?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Punctuated_Aramaic&lang=bi):

> הַהוּא דְּאָמַר: דּוּנוּ דִּינִי. אָמְרִי: שְׁמַע מִינַּהּ מִדָּן קָאָתֵי, דִּכְתִיב: ״דָּן יָדִין עַמּוֹ כְּאַחַד שִׁבְטֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל״.
> With regard to the precision required in language, the Gemara relates: A certain man would regularly say whenever involved in conflict: Adjudicate my case [dunu dini]. The Sages said: Learn from it that he descends from the tribe of Dan, as it is written: “Dan will judge [yadin] his people like one of the tribes of Israel” (Genesis 49:16). He expressed himself that way due to his lineage.
> הָהוּא דַּהֲוָה קָא אָזֵיל וְאָמַר: אַכֵּיף יַמָּא אָסֵיסְנִי בִּירָאתָא. בְּדַקוּ וְאַשְׁכְּחוּהוּ דְּמִזְּבוּלוּן קָאָתֵי, דִּכְתִיב: ״זְבוּלֻן לְחוֹף יַמִּים יִשְׁכֹּן״.
> The Gemara relates a similar incident: A certain man would regularly walk and say: The bushes on the seashore are cypresses (ge’onim), i.e., items located by the sea are more beautiful than those found in other places. They examined his lineage and found that he descends from the tribe of Zebulun, as it is written: “Zebulun shall dwell by the seashore” (Genesis 49:13). That explains his love of all things close to the sea.

The second is from the [letter of Aristeas](https://www.sefaria.org/Letter_of_Aristeas.46?lang=en&with=About&lang2=en), from the time of the Second Temple:

> In the presence of all the people I selected **six elders from each tribe**, good men and true, and I have sent them to you with a copy of our law. It will be a kindness, O righteous king, if you will give instruction that as soon as the translation of the law is completed, the men shall be restored again to us in safety. Farewell.'
> 47The following are the names of the elders: Of the first tribe, Joseph, Ezekiah, Zachariah, John, Ezekiah, Elisha. Of the second tribe, Judas, Simon, Samuel, Adaeus, Mattathias, Eschlemias. Of the third tribe, Nehemiah, Joseph, Theodosius, Baseas, Ornias, Dakis.
> 48Of the fourth tribe, Jonathan, Abraeus, Elisha, Ananias, Chabrias.... Of the fifth tribe, Isaac, Jacob, Jesus, Sabbataeus, Simon, Levi. Of the sixth tribe, Judas, Joseph, Simon, Zacharias, Samuel, Selemias.
> 49Of the seventh tribe, Sabbataeus, Zedekiah, Jacob, Isaac, Jesias, Natthaeus. Of the eighth tribe Theodosius, Jason, Jesus, Theodotus, John, Jonathan. Of the ninth tribe, Theophilus, Abraham Arsamos, Jason, Endemias, Daniel.
> 50Of the tenth tribe, Jeremiah, Eleazar, Zachariah, Baneas, Elisha, Dathaeus. Of the eleventh tribe, Samuel, Joseph, Judas, Jonathes, Chabu, Dositheus. Of the twelfth tribe, Isaelus, John, Theodosius, Arsamos, Abietes, Ezekiel. **They were seventy-two in all.**

This is also quoted by [Josephus](https://www.sefaria.org/The_Antiquities_of_the_Jews.12.2.6?lang=he). For more on the letter of Aristeas, see [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SxtDOfDbNs)

Comment: I also think this is implied by https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.12.17?ven=The_Metsudah_Tanach_series,_Lakewood,_N.J&lang=bi&with=Translations&lang2=en, but it is not 100% conclusive.